# I want to block assets folder path in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, assets

Am new in **Codeigniter** i want to block `assets` folder in my website. I mean website `users(website viewer)` enter `http://www.example.com/assets` it move to `404` page.

Please help me...!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you put assets in the main directory outside application folder.

Comment: Yeah `assets` folder in outside of application folder only

Comment: I know its solved but when you come across it you could try with index.php in url `http://www.example.com/index.php/assets/css/stylesheet.css`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your assets folder is there to serve things like CSS, JavaScript and image files (like would be intended), and is an actual directory, then you can either do this by adding a .htaccess file to the directory (assuming it's running under Apache) which will take all requests which are not for explicit file paths and route them to the website controller/action for a 404 (or other page you use for this).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/path/to/404 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Alternatively, you can add an `index.php` file which redirects the browser to the location for a 404 page, or displays a 404 type page as a response.

```
header("Location: http://yourdomain.com/path/to/404");
```

Comment: And one more thing how can i control menu `class="active"` in controller

Comment: @MuduK you'd need to raise a different question for that as it's a separate issue, and it would all depend on the code you have in the controller and view to be able to enable it

Comment: `css`,`js`,`images` not loaded in 404 page. Here am using `echo base_url("assets/css/style.css")` but it showing `Message: Call to undefined function base_url()`. I checked in `config.php` and `autoload.php` files. `$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');` also correct

Comment: Does the 404 page route through codeigniter, or have you set the index.php to look like a 404?  If it's the latter, it's because it doesn't know about CodeIgniter and the functions available.  I personally always run things like that through an error controller (so have something like `error/404` as a route).  This lets me set the HTTP status code, and use all of the built in CodeIgniter functionality